# What is the difference between PackageReference Update and PackageReference Include?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget-package

```xml
<PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.1.22" />
<PackageReference Include="Platform.Core" Version="1.8.0" />
```

What is the difference between "Update" and "Include" in the above two lines?

Comment: Did you checked https://codeopinion.com/nuget-packagereference-versions-solution-wide/ article. It may help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022).

It looks like `Update` is used when you want to modify only some properties on a pre-existing item with the same name

So you could do:

```
<PackageReference Include="Some.Package" Version="1.2.3"/>
<PackageReference Update="Some.Package" PrivateAssets="all"/>
```

The `Update` line would add the `PrivateAssets="all"` property to the pre-existing `Some.Package` item, with the end result being the same as:

```
<PackageReference Include="Some.Package" Version="1.2.3" PrivateAssets="all"/>
```

If you had used `Include` instead of `Update`, you'd have overwritten the first line entirely, and lost the `Version="1.2.3"` property.

Note that just using `Update` when there isn't a pre-existing item to update seems to be harmless, but is pointless.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually upgrading my .net 2.1 to 6.0. I updated the tfm to "net6.0". That means, having this "Microsoft.NETCore.App" package update to "2.1.22" is pointless when in reality the 6.0.x will be in the picture due to the net6.0 upgrade. Right?

Comment: @ArunPrakashNagendran You don't need "Microsoft.NETCore.App" in a .NET 6 application. I'm not sure exactly when it became irrelevant, but you definitely don't need it these days

Comment: I observed that this was not needed when I created a fresh .net6.0 project. Here, I was upgrading my .net core(2.1 to 6)  and found this entry in the .csproj file which made me wonder if this was really needed. Thanks for your clarifications. I appreciate it.