# .Net csproj files - what is the difference between "Reference Include" and "Reference Update"?

Tags: .net, csproj

I've converted some old csproj files to Sdk Style using .Net upgrade assistant and now I see the following lines inside the upgraded csproj files:

```
<Reference Update="System.Core" />
<Reference Update="System.Xml.Linq" />
```

It was ***`<Reference Include="System.Core" />`"*** before the update.

What is the difference between ***Reference Include*** and ***Reference update***?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between PackageReference Update and PackageReference Include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71660693/what-is-the-difference-between-packagereference-update-and-packagereference-incl)

Comment: @tananas do let us know if the mentioned article is enough. You can delete these as the assistant leaves them in and changes include to update because the new SDK already includes these references by default (and so the existing ones get turned into update but don't contain any additional metadata that would need to change so it's pointless)